# running .bashrc versus new login

Tags: linux, bashrc

I added new alias into .bashrc

Running .bashrc doesn't create that alias but new log in yes.

Could you somebody explain why is that so and how I can test if the new .bashrc works without doing test log in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"exec bash" should do it.  Basically just restarts the bash shell, reading .bashrc in the process.

Comment: let me try that... so why executing .bashrc doesn't work?

Comment: When you execute ".bashrc" by itself it starts a new bash shell up (reading your new aliases) but keeps the old one active.  Then it "does nothing" since you didn't ask it to do anything, and exits back to the old shell, restoring all your old aliases.

Comment: When you "exec bash" it REPLACES your old shell with the new one.  "man exec" for all the details of how this works.  It's also useful if your root account runs sh but you like bash better for some things (cwd in prompt in my case).  You can make root run bash by "exec bash" as root.

Comment: very nice explanation ...

Answer (score 8):

You can source the file using `.` or `source`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

That will re-read and execute the lines in the file in the current session.

Comment: works nicely....